# smtp host is not working in godaddy

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i'm using php, to send emails i'm using phpmailer...and i configure with smtp server for send mails through php. Everything works fine in localhost but when i host my website into godaddy. it shows an while sending mails...

here's my code for sending mails..through phpmailer.

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
{                       
    require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
    $mail->Port       = 465;             
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Username="foo@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password='bar';            
    $mail->SetFrom($email,'Postcam');
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email,"Postcam");
    $mail->Subject   = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->Send();
}
```

And i search in different websites...finally i got one answer.. godaddy blocks the smtp connection to force his customers to using oum host like "reley-secureserver.net".
Is it right..

Comment: You see `$mail->SMTPDebug`, use it..

Comment: Here is a [list of SMTP restrictions for popular hosts](http://docs.mailpoet.com/article/49-lists-of-hosts-and-their-sending-limits). Note you need to use `foo@my-godaddy-site.com`, not `foo@gmail.com`.

Comment: According to that list.... godaddy owns a specific host for their customers...to send emails.  I think now, it is not possible to use gmail smtp host in godaddy. right?

Comment: Try ssl://smtp.gmail.com , and make sure check out https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Go to your GoDaddy cPanel > MX Records and then select the domain that you want to be sending from.  Make sure that 'Remote Mail Exchanger' is selected if you are sending through a Gmail email address.